# Class containing field of another class and how is it changed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have the following scenario. I have a class A containing a field of type B (another class). The object of type B is injected into A using dependency injection. B is registered as transient.

Now, what I am confused with is that if the B's object changes because of some event, will that change be reflected in A's object?

```
class A
{

   B bObj;

   A(B obj)
   {
     bObj = obj;
   }

public void SomeMethod()
{
  StorageLayerClient sClient = bObj.GetStorageLayerClient();
  sClient.DoSomethingFromStorageLayer();
}

}


class B
{
 StorageLayerClient sClient;

 StorageLayerClient GetStorageLayerClient()
 {
   return this.sClient;
 }

public void RecreateStorageClient()
{
  //recreate storage client when notified via Event
}
}
```

Comment: How do you register `B` in DI? As a singleton, as a transient?

Comment: "B" is registered as transient.

Comment: In short: no, because every instance of `B` will be different as this is what transient lifetime is supposed to be. Dependency injection and lifetime it provides are one of fundamental concepts in .NET application programming, I strongly suggest reading this [piece of documentation about DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection).